# compiling 64 bit linux kernel with gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, 64-bit, linux-kernel, x86-64

While trying to compile a 64 bit linux kernel using gcc, I see the
following error :

**kernel/bounds.c:1: error: code model ‘kernel’ not supported in the 32
bit mode 

kernel/bounds.c:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in**

This is what **gcc -v** reports :
Using built-in specs.
Target: i586-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --
infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/
bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --
enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --
disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c+
+,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-
plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --
enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/
usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --
with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch=i586 --build=i586-redhat-
linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2) (GCC)

Am i missing something on my kernel make command line ?
Or is it the gcc present on the system does not support 64 bit
compilation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compiler is 32-bit.

Comment: Where can i find 64 bit gcc? Or how do i compile gcc to support 64 bit compilation?

Comment: After building a compiler with x86_64 bit support, the kernel build failed nonetheless. I tried installing fedora core rpm for kernel-devel-x86_64. This failed too. This was root caused to be an earlier P4 CPU which perhaps does not support 64 bit.

Comment: oh, you're to reinstall the system completely if you want to change the architecture of your OS frm 32 to 64bit.  However, on most 64-bit processors everything 32bit will keep up running.

Answer (score 4):

What system are you running on?

If you host system is running in 32 bit mode you'll have to build a cross-compiler targeting x86_64. If your system is a 64bit system then your vendor should be providing you with a system compiler capable off building 64bit executables.

What does "uname -a" say on your system?

Comment: I am quite sure its running in 32-bit mode. 
uname -a 
Linux host.vivekian.com 2.6.29.4-167.fc11.i586 #1 SMP Wed May 27 17:14:37 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

How do i build gcc to target x86-64 ?