# Linux kernel 4.8.4 does not compile on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Trying to compile Linux kernel 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 16.10 gives the following error.

```
$ make
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  VDSO    arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso64.so.dbg
  OBJCOPY arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso64.so
  VDSO2C  arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso-image-64.c
  CC      arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso-image-64.o
  AS      arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32/note.o
arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32/note.S:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: -mfentry isn’t supported for 32-bit in combination with -fpic
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 

$ uname -a
Linux ThinkPad-X61s 4.8.1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Oct 9 20:34:38 EEST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compiling 64 bit linux kernel with gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370803/compiling-64-bit-linux-kernel-with-gcc)

Comment: I don't think it is the same problem. I have 64bit kernel, 64bit gcc.

Comment: make menuconfig. Have been compiling kernel for years with no problems. Used the same .config to compile 4.8.1 with 16.04 Ubuntu. Kernel 4.8.4 compilation fails with 16.10 error mentioned above.

Comment: Ah, just noticed your GCC version. Try to use GCC 5 or even GCC 4.9. Seems like kernel doesn't support GCC 6 yet (particularly, it doesn't support building vdso with `-mfentry` flag). Or you can `filter-out` that `-mfentry` flag, like proposed [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/2/16/15).

Comment: Try building with [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/android-x86/kernel/ci/f72848dae7017c97d2ea72c2ec16948797beca66/) patch.

Comment: That patch did the trick! Now kernel compiles again. Thanks a bunch Sam.